# SAML Authentication across multiple SP's

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have portal A for which I've implemented SAML authentication with an SP (Azure AD). In portal A, I will show some screens from Portal B as Iframe.

Both portal A and portal B uses SAML based authentication from the same IDP (Azure AD).

Situation here is users login into Portal A and when tried to access pages where Portal B screens are shown as Iframes, they have to initiate a SAML login again (However they are not prompted to enter their credentials now
as they are already logged into Portal A using SAML authentication)

I was initially under the impression that when Portal A is authenticated against IDP, this will establish an SSO against all the portals which uses the same IDP for authentication. But now I understand that it is not how it works.

Is it possible to achieve SSO for all SP's which uses the same IDP for authentication when the user has successfully authenticated himself with one SP need not be prompted to login for all other SP's using samle IDP's?

Comment: Your problem description is a bit unclear, but as long as the user is authenticated with the IdP (usually triggered by accessing the first SP), no credentials should be required to authenticate with subsequent SPs.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Yes, no credentials are required with Subsequent SP'. But why should the user be redirected to Login page of subsequent SP's ? On Subsequent SP's - he is required to click the Login button, from where he is taken to STS portal again and then only he is successfully authenticated across the other SP. Though he is not prompted to re-enter his credentials there, I am thinking, instead of user clicking the login button on the subsequent SP's would it be possible to authenticate the user directly without asking him to click the login button on subsequent sp's.

Comment: The fact that the user is required to click a Login button on SP side is an SP implementation detail and should be handled there. Looks like you want some sort of feature where the IdP automatically authenticates the user to all SPs. No idea if Azure AD supports this.

Comment: Thanks Robby. That was indeed my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `isPassive` option in the SAML authentication request that allows the SP to check whether the user is authenticated at an IDP without any interaction with the user, regardless of the status (i.e. authenticated vs. unauthenticated). See https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf section 3.4.1:

> **IsPassive** [Optional]
>   A Boolean value. If "true", the identity provider
>   and the user agent itself MUST NOT visibly take control of the user
>   interface from the requester and interact with the presenter in a
>   noticeable fashion. If a value is not provided, the default is
>   "false".

A SP could use that in an iframe that does not display to the user to find out whether to pop the "Login" button or not. If the user is authenticated a SAML response will be returned without bothering the user and an application session can be created. If the user is not authenticated, the SAML response will indicate that and the "Login" button can be shown.

This does rely on the fact that the SP knows which IDP to ask.

There is no standardized way to logon the user to all SPs in one go but the IDP could implement such functionality in something like an enterprise portal that launches iframes to the SP with IDP-initiated-SSO SAML responses.